# Add tags based on the date of the last reply to a thread in GMail using a Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I've created a Google Apps script for my GMail account. It goes through emails in my @ACTIONS folder and adds tags depending on how old it is.

For example, this part of the script adds the tag **1 WEEK OLD** when the email is over a week old:

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('label:@actions older_than:7d newer_than:14d -(label:1 WEEK OLD) ');
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("1 WEEK OLD");

for (var t in threads) {
  threads[t].addLabel(label);
};
```

I've got other ones that add tags for 3 DAYS, 2 WEEKS OLD and 30 DAYS OLD.
When the email has been moved outside the @ACTIONS folder, the tags are removed:

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('-(label:@actions) (label:1 WEEK OLD)');
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("1 WEEK OLD");

for (var t in threads) {
  threads[t].removeLabel(label);
};
```

The problem is that the Gmail search function: older_than works on the initial email in the thread - not the final email. So, the tags are being shown even if there is a reply later. For example, an email that was received a couple of months ago is having the 30 DAYS tag added despite it being replied to within the last week.

Is there a way to add these tags based on date of the last reply - not the original email's date.

The full script is here: https://pastebin.com/Xdv8U5eV

Thanks!

Comment: Using the Gmail advanced service, you can perform per-message label assignment with [`Gmail.Messages.modify`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) and [`.batchModify`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/batchModify) The behavior of Gmail, in which viewing a conversation thread shows all labels from all messages, cannot be changed with Apps Script.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how I would use `Gmail.Messages.modify` for this. I'm fine with the default view of showing all labels from all messages, but I'd like the label for the thread to show the label based on the date of the latest email in the thread. If there was a way to label based on the latest email of the thread, that would be my solution.

Comment: In my code, where `t` is the thread, is there a way to find out the date of the latest email. And then work out how many days ago it was? Then I could just add the label.

Comment: Ah ok, I have found `getLastMessageDate()` so this should help.

Comment: Ah got it! Let me do some testing, but getLastMessageDate() looks like the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the problem. What I need is to do an IF statement with `getLastMessageDate()`:

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('label:@actions) older_than:1d newer_than:3d -(label:1 DAY OLD) ');
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("1 DAY OLD");
var minDays = 1 // Enter # of days
var maxDays = 3 // Enter # of days
var minDate = new Date();
var maxDate = new Date();
minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate()-minDays);
maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-maxDays);

for (var t in threads) {
   if (threads[t].getLastMessageDate()>maxDate && threads[t].getLastMessageDate()<minDate )
      {
          threads[t].addLabel(label);
      };
};
```